# Change value of iterator of parent for loop in nested for loop?

Tags: python, loops

So, I am trying to solve competitive programming using Python and came across a problem which required use of nested loops. I used nested for loop and incremented the value of iterator of parent for loop if certain condition is met in the child for loop. But when the child for loop ends, the value of iterator of parent for loop doesn't change.

Example:

```
for i in range(5):
    print "When i = %d" % (i)
    for j in range(i+1,5):
        print j
        if j % 2 == 0:
            i = j
```

Output:

```
When i = 0
1
2
3
4
When i = 1
2
3
4
....
```

How to increment the value of I and make the loop run less times, as I want to decrease the CPU time and cycles?

Comment: make use of `while` loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I may have been incorrect in my assertion of variable scope, but regardless, the `for` loop follows the looping variable definition independent of how you attempt to define the looping variable within the loop.

Here is an example of what's happening with your script. No matter how you set `i`, it will still go through the entire `range(5)`.

```
In [1]: for i in range(5):
    print(i)
    i=10
    print(i)

Out [1]: 0
10 
1
10 
2
10 
3
10 
4
10
```

You need a `while` loop instead of a `for` loop, so you can redefine any variable within the loop. If I understood your exact problem correctly, I think you're looking for this:

```
i = 0   # initialize i 
while i<4:      # ensure i stops at no more than 4 in the final iteration
    print "When i = %d" % i
    for j in range(i+1,5):
        print j
        if j % 2 == 0:
            i = j
            break       # break out of the j loop if this condition is met
    else:       # iterate i if none of the 'j %...' conditions are met ('break' is not encountered)
        i+=1
```

Answer (score 2):

in python, if you wanna change the `value` of the `iterator` in a `loop`, you should use `while loop`. Your question isn't clear enough about what you want to achieve, but an example would be:

```
i = 0
while i < 5:
    print "When i = %d" % (i)
    i+=1
    for j in range(i,5):
        print j
        if j % 2 == 0:
            i = j
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem isn't clear enough, but if you wanted to change the `for` loop you should directly consider using the `while` loop